# Show all categories pages in WordPress sitemap?

Tags: wordpress

Good day, dear specialists. There is such a code

```
$categoriesForSitemap = get_categories(array(
 'hide_empty' => 1, 
 'depth' => 0, 
 'hierarchical' => false
 ));
foreach($categoriesForSitemap as $category) {
    $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
    $sitemap .= '<url>' . '<loc>' . get_category_link($category->term_id) . '</loc>' . '<priority>1</priority>' . '<lastmod></lastmod>' . '<changefreq>daily</changefreq>' . '</url>';
}
```

How can I enable adding all category pages in it? Those.

```
category-name/page/2/ 

category-name/page/3/
.....
```

and so on.

Plase help me. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WordPress so why not just use a plugin that does it for you already? There must be a plugin that is free that supports this already.

Comment: I don't use a plugin. I generate a special xml file to update the cache

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `depth` option in `get_categories()`.
Second, you set the `hide_empty` and `hierarchical` parameters yourself - as a result, you will no have ALL categories.
Thirdly, in the loop you refer to `$cat->cat_ID` - it is not at all clear what.
My advice is read the documentation before asking questions on stackoverflow.